# Databar in SSRS throws exception While integrating With ASP.net

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services, rdlc

I am creating report using SSRS that shows databars. It works fine with RDL file. when I am integrating it in ASP.Net shows following error.

The Maximum expression for the chart 'DataBar1' contains an aggregate function (or RunningValue or RowNumber functions) in the argument to another aggregate function (or RunningValue).  Aggregate functions cannot be nested inside other aggregate functions.

Any idea to resolve this error.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue.  I realise that this question was asked a while ago, but I searched for help before resolving, so am putting this here in the hope it may help someone else.

In my case it was caused by the databar using SUMs to determine the values for the bar, and the horizontal axis maximum being set to Auto.  I think that what was happening in that case is that the axis maximum was effectively set to MAX(SUM(whatever)) which is not permitted.

I worked around it by altering my query and changing the values to being a percentage (still using SUM) and hard coding the MAX to 0.5.  It's not ideal, of course.  The other way would be to look at whether or not you can pull the value from the SQL somehow.